# How to change/add css to dynamically generated checkbox class

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, checkbox, checked

I have an jquery accordion, when i click on the accordion header an ajax call brings up the content. each of these contents has a list of items with checkboxes and a submit button so user can update database (via another ajax call).

when submit is clicked i want to remove the checkbox of all the checked items and then style these specific items. I can remove the checkboxes but i can't seem to add change the css! of the items that were checked. can anyone help ? 
 the html goes like so

```
Html
     accordion header <h3>(dynamic id)
    div class row
    div class bootstrap
    checkbox class single-checkbox (dynamic id)
    <p> content </p>




  checkbox

<input type="checkbox"  class="single-checkbox" name="contentAll[]" value="<?php echo $row2['bing'], '-', $row2['content_all']; ?>" />

jquery

    $('.submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "heir3.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $('.single-checkbox:checked').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
    $('.single-checkbox:checked').remove();}   
    }); 
    });

submit
<button class="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: just add class using jquery .addClass('someClassName') to your items that were checked and then write CSS for those items in your css file

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` then store the styles in there:

CSS

```
.my-checkbox-class {
    // styles
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.single-checkbox:checked').addClass('my-checkbox-class');
$('.single-checkbox:checked').removeClass('my-checkbox-class');
```

You can add any styles to any element like this and remove them too. It's a good, clean solution that makes your css re-usable and keeps the style and functionality separate.

Note that the add and remove class methods don't need a `.` to denote a class, this can be a gotcha

Comment: Hi, thankyou, i saw this method but it doesn't work in my code. maybe its where I'm putting it?

I put it like so    

{    $('.submit').click(function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: "heir3.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $('.single-checkbox:checked').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {

$('.single-checkbox:checked').addClass('my-checkbox-class');
 }

 });
 
});

sorry about the editing, i can't work out how to edit.

Comment: I put this jQuery code at the top and it somewhat does what i want but it doesnt do it in the order I want, when the submit button is clicked.
<blockquote>
$("input:radio,input:checkbox").change(function () {
   $(this)
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
       .next('label')
           .css('color', 'red');
});

Comment: @CDog have you double checked the contents of `$('.single-checkbox:checked')` at the point you add the class? You can use [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) to pause js and examine variables in the console (you can also use backticks to denote code in a Stack Overflow comment, as you would in a post, which makes it much easier to read :-)

Comment: i'm new to jQuery, and don't know how to debug, i think firefox has one. i will spend tonight trying to understand how it works.  i suppose i can't understand why `('.single-checkbox:checked')` recognises `.remove` but not `.addClass`? wah

Comment: I ended up adding this and it worked

`$('.single-checkbox:checked').next('p').addClass('my-checkbox-class');
 $('.single-checkbox:checked').remove();`

i check it in firebug but i can't see a difference between the code that worked and the code that didn't. is there a any easy to use 'firebug for dummies'? 

or can someone point me in the right direction to see selector information?